# Element in array is masked or no

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to check a single element in a numpy array, I need to know if it is masked the element.

```
y,x=np.mgrid[slice(0,25, 1),slice(0,43, 1)]         
z=pp[y,x,_mapa_]
z = np.ma.masked_where(_mascara<0.5,z)

for _x in range(24,0,-1):
     for _y in range(0,43,1):
          print z[-_x,_y]  NEED TO NOW IF IS MASKED OR NOT, TO THE NEXT LEVEL
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I resolve

to check one element in array is:

```
z[-_x,_y].mask  give me true
```

Sorry this not resolve the question. Give me elements that have mask, but elements that not have mask not give me False.

Ok I find a solution

```
z[-_x,_y] is np.ma.masked  with this give you True or False
```

Comment: You can also use `z.mask[_x,_y]` that is either True or False in the same way.